# Drupal 7 edit account not available for users

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, administration, user-accounts

I have a strange problem with my drupal 7 installation.

I need my registered users can change their account options like the password.

I've installed several modules on my site to try to force the "edit account" tab appear in the user page ( domainname.ext/user/me )
but it doesn't work for users, but it works only for the administrator user.

I've checked every permission and it seems all setted up properly.

References:
Image 1: the admin page - 
Image 2: the user page

[image: The tab with the admin account]

[image: The tab with another account]

How can i fix it?
Why the edit account tab doesn't appear in the user page, but only on the administrator page?

Comment: What does your permissions page look like for the user/profile section?

Comment: I've solved it: there was a custom module that made a conflict with user settings!
:)